# View excel in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am new to programming in MVC.

My question is:

On a button click I want to choose an excel file stored on the computer and view it in the application. Preferably in a table or something? Is this possible?

Thanks for help.